# Server is terminated when started in subshell

Tags: shell, typesafe-activator, playframework-2.4

I build a small script that should run the server in development mode asynchronously and execute a few commands afterwards. Somehow, when the command is set inside a scripts subshell, the server starts but is terminated after two three seconds..

The subshell

```
( ./activator run ) &
```

Can I start the sever asynchronously inside a script and when how, or are there other solutions with shell?

Comment: Does the server give any indication of *why* it is terminating? Anything in the logs or output to the screen?

Comment: The log just list that the server is started. The output is not different to the one, if I enter './activator run' in a terminal. When I enter it manually in a terminal I can then terminate the server manually with ctrl-d. Then it prints out a success message. This message is printed after two, three seconds, when server is started in a subshell.

Comment: The server runs in the foreground? That's probably the problem then. Your backgrounded sub-shell runs out of "input" for it to read. That seems like a strange "server" though. Can you get it to run itself in the background? Can you manually redirect standard input? Something like `./activator run < /dev/zero`? (Though that might cause it to use a huge amount of cpu if it is constantly trying to read from standard input.)